# Name of solitaire game with layout like US flag?

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

[image]

The layout is as shown in the picture.  I call it the “flag version”of solitaire, but that is my own made up name.  My grandmother taught it to me.

Stacks are moved to make descending order stacks but in the same suit, not red on black / black on red.  For example, the four of diamonds may be moved to be on top of the five of diamonds.  The cards on top of four move with it.

The three leftover cards may be played at any time.  Kings can be moved to empty columns.  The cards in the upper left may be turned face up one at a time when revealed.

Winning condition is every suit is stacked alone in order, King to Ace.

Answer (score 3):

You've described a version of [Scorpion Solitaire](https://www.bvssolitaire.com/rules/scorpion.htm), but with more cards face up than the usual version.

> Set up
> Scorpion Solitaire uses one deck (52 cards). You have 7 tableau piles. Three rows of 7 cards are dealt - the first 4 cards face down and the next 3 face up in each row. Then four more rows of 7 cards are dealt, all face up. The remaining 3 cards are put face down as a reserve.
>
> The object of the game
> To build four sequences down in suit within the tableau, each running from King to Ace.
>
> The rules
> You may build tableau piles down in suit. Groups of cards can be moved regardless of any sequence. Any face up card in a tableau can be moved to make a build. All the cards covering it are moved together as a unit. If, during play, any closed cards become the top card of a pile it turns face up.
>
> Empty tableaus may be filled with a King or group of cards headed by a King.
>
> When you have made all the moves initially available, click on the reserve pile to deal the 3 remaining cards face up to the three leftmost piles.